# How to set the starting folder in an <input type="file"> element

Tags: html

From reading related questions, I get the impression that setting a default file is prohibited for security reasons.

Can I set a starting folder instead?

If not, how can I help my users to easily navigate to a common location? I'd really hate to have to make them copy/paste a long folder.

Comment: The file chooser that pops up is relevant to their native environment, so you aren't going to be able to do much with that. How would you know the folder exists, or what it's called?

Comment: In my particular example, my users need to store the links to files on a network share. Unfortunately, I realized that the input tag won't give me access to the full path in anycase, so I need to find another way to do this.

Comment: Yeah sadly that inputwon't give you anywhere near the amount of flexibility, if it's even possible.